# NetNamedPipeBinding create an issue when service is restarted

Tags: wcf

We are using WCF service with NetNamedPipeBinding binding. It works without any problem.But some time when we replace service's bin in IIS or restart the service then client can not connect with service. During this error If we change the binding from NetNamedPipeBinding to BasicHttpBinding in client side then work perfectly.

Client does not receive the response from the service. So how we can overcome from this issue and just want to know what is the actual issue with NetNamedPipeBinding?

if there is an any better replacement of NetNamedPipeBinding.

Update:

Service side configuration

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServicesBehavior" name="WcfServices.Service1">
    <endpoint address="soap" behaviorConfiguration="FlattenWsdlEndpointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServices.IService1">
     <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
     </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfServices.IService1" />
  <endpoint address="NamedPipe" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="WcfServices.IService1" />
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

Client side configuration

```
<client>
 <endpoint address="http://someAddress/WcfServices/Service1.svc/soap"   binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="WcfServices.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
 <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/WcfServices/Service1.svc/NamedPipe" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IService1" contract="WcfServices.IService1" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

Thanks in advance.

If someone can help me on this.

Comment: _"[is] there is a any better replacement of NetNamedPipeBinding"_ - certainly.  [NetTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) is arguably the next best for LANs but it's not as fast as pipes.

Comment: Please show us your code, especially your config.

Comment: @Jacob - Here is the Config code